# How to update the value of a character variable using concatenation?

Tags: sas, concatenation

I am using SAS EG, and in the following MWE, I am trying to update an existing character variable by concatenating some new characters to it.

```
    data tmp;
input z $;
cards;
a
a
a
;
run;

data tmp2;
set tmp;
s ='x';
t = s || 'y';
s = s || 'y';
run;

data tmp3;
set tmp2;
a = 0;
do i=1 to 4;
    a = a+i;
    s = s || 'y';
end;
run;
```

So, this code will concatenate the two strings in t, but it does not update s. However, it does not have the same problem with numbers and as you cans see it can update at each cycle of the loop. So, can anyone tell me why it happens to character variables and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because sas numbers ([numeric](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#numvar.htm)) have a default length of 8 which is approximatly 15 digit floating point, but your `s` is char with length=1.

You can confirm by running `Proc SQL Describe Table` and checking the log:

**Debug:**

```
Proc sql; describe table tmp2; quit;
```

**Log:**

```
create table WORK.TMP2( bufsize=4096 )
  (
   z char(8),
   s char(1),
   t char(3)
  );
```

**Fix:**

1. use `Length` statement to assign the length
2. use `Cats()` or `Catx()` for concatenation instead of ||; this will remove leading and trailing spaces

**Code:**

```
data tmp2;
set tmp;
length s $10 ;
s ='x';
t = cats(s,'y');
s = cats(s,'y');
run;

data tmp3;
set tmp2;
a = 0;
do i=1 to 4;
    a = a+i;
    s=cats(s,'y');
end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. It works perfectly fine. Now I understand what is happening. So, basically, SAS was truncating the variable and I needed to set a larger length to stop it.Thanks again. Keep doing great my friend.

Comment: you are welcome, just remember to use cats() when concatenating, as sas usually adds trailing spaces.

Comment: SAS numbers are floating point. They have a length of 8 because SAS using 64 bit floating point numbers. Perhaps you meant that the maximum number of significant digits is about 15?

Comment: Yeah, I tried with both cats() and catx(). I needed to remove the trailing space and also add a delimiter to it. Thanks again for the great and precise answer.

Comment: @Tom, thanks. I updated my answer with clearer details on the numeric default.

Answer (score 1):

When a character variable is initialized in SAS it is assigned a length.  In your example, the length assigned to variable `s` was given a length of 1 as when you initialized it, you assigned a string of length 1 to it.

The solution is to use a `length` statement to declare how long you would like the string to be beforehand:

```
length s $2;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. It works perfectly fine.